# Change or extend, the behavior of save button product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

help with the following.

I have to add more functionality to the save button product, checking I found that you can do with plug-ins that provides Magento2.

As I can change or extend the functionality or performance of the save button product in Magento 2?.

What is the class to observed?.

[image]

Comment: u can see https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Overriding-a-controller-in-Magento-2/td-p/6832

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then, for the save button product, which would extend the class?

Comment: class save product  `Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save`.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. You can using `plug-ins` to extend functionality of save button. Based on your requirement you can use methods `before{method}`, `around{method}`, `after{method}` .

You can create `di.xml` with following code to implement plug-in

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save">
<plugin name="magento-catalog-admin-controller-plugin" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

In your module's `Save.php`, use methods `before{method}`, `around{method}`, `after{method}`

If you want to override `Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Save`, you can use `preferences` instead of `plug-ins` .